# alignat* inside tabular: "Extra & on this line"

Tags: tables, arrays, alignat

I've been struggling with this error for hours now and I have not found a solution yet.

I have two environments (one is an `alignat*` and one is an `array`), and I need to put them side-by-side.
If I don't put them inside a `tabular`, everything works fine.

I get this error: "Package amsmath Error: Extra & on this line." (the line is: `\end{alignat*}}`)
The code is this:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
{\begin{alignat*}{3}
    41708 &= 2 \cdot 20854 &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    20854 &= 2 \cdot 10427 &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    10427 &= 2 \cdot 5213  &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    5213  &= 2 \cdot 2606  &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    2606  &= 2 \cdot 1303  &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    1303  &= 2 \cdot 651   &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    651   &= 2 \cdot 325   &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    325   &= 2 \cdot 162   &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    162   &= 2 \cdot 81    &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    81    &= 2 \cdot 40    &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    40    &= 2 \cdot 20    &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    20    &= 2 \cdot 10    &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    10    &= 2 \cdot 5     &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    5     &= 2 \cdot 2     &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    2     &= 2 \cdot 1     &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    1     &= 2 \cdot 0     &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
\end{alignat*}}
&
$
  \begin{array}{cccc||>{\centering\arraybackslash\boldmath$}m{0.7cm}<{$}}
    x & y & z & w & f\\\hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\%\hline

    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\%\hline

    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\%\hline

    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
  \end{array}
$
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to put them side-by-side, you can use `minipage` instead of a `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    41708 &= 2 \cdot 20854 &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    20854 &= 2 \cdot 10427 &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    10427 &= 2 \cdot 5213  &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    5213  &= 2 \cdot 2606  &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    2606  &= 2 \cdot 1303  &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    1303  &= 2 \cdot 651   &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    651   &= 2 \cdot 325   &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    325   &= 2 \cdot 162   &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    162   &= 2 \cdot 81    &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    81    &= 2 \cdot 40    &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    40    &= 2 \cdot 20    &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    20    &= 2 \cdot 10    &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    10    &= 2 \cdot 5     &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    5     &= 2 \cdot 2     &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
    2     &= 2 \cdot 1     &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{0}}\\
    1     &= 2 \cdot 0     &&+ \ \fbox{\textbf{1}}\\
\end{alignat*}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}
\(
  \begin{array}{cccc||>{\centering\boldmath\arraybackslash}m{0.7cm}}
    x & y & z & w & f\\\hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\%\hline

    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\%\hline

    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\%\hline

    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
  \end{array}
\)
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can have a simpler code, using  `alignedat` and `array` nested in a signle `align*` environment. Note that using `alignat(3)` requires 5 `&`, not 3 (each column but the first has to be introduced by an `&`, and contains a second `&` for the alignment point inside this column).  I also thought  that using `hhline` would the array look nicer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{alignedat}{3}     41708 &= 2 \cdot 20854 &&{} +{} & \ & \boxed{\mathbf{0}}\\
 20854 &= 2 \cdot 10427 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{0}}\\
 10427 &= 2 \cdot 5213 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{1}}\\
 5213 &= 2 \cdot 2606 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{1}}\\
 2606 &= 2 \cdot 1303 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{0}}\\
 1303 &= 2 \cdot 651 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{1}}\\
 651 &= 2 \cdot 325 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{1}}\\
 325 &= 2 \cdot 162 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{1}}\\
 162 &= 2 \cdot 81 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{0}}\\
 81 &= 2 \cdot 40 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{1}}\\
 40 &= 2 \cdot 20 & & +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{0}}\\
 20 &= 2 \cdot 10 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{0}}\\
 10 &= 2 \cdot 5 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{0}}\\
 5 &= 2 \cdot 2 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{1}}\\
 2 &= 2 \cdot 1 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{0}}\\
 1 &= 2 \cdot 0 && +{} && \boxed{\mathbf{1}}
\end{alignedat}
 \hspace{4em}
  \begin{array}{cccc||>{\centering\boldmath\arraybackslash}m{0.7cm}}
    x & y & z & w & f\\
    \hhline{----||-}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\%\hline
%
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\%\hline
%
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\%\hline
%
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\boxed{\mathbf{0}}` is simpler (and more correct). Actually, the outer `align*` doesn't seem the best approach: just use `equation*` and add a suitable space between the two big objects. Or simply `$...$` as probably this will go in a float.

Comment: @egreg: I confess  I didn't even think  of  this problem, but you're perfectly right, and I'll change the code.